# Making a Screenshot in LibGDX by Pressing the Prt Scr Button

Tags: java, libgdx, printscreen

By following [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Taking-a-Screenshot) solution on Stack Overflow I have come up with the following Java class:

```
public final class Screenshot {

    private static byte[] pixels;
    private static Pixmap pixmap;

    public static void take() {
        pixels = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels(0, 0,
                Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth(),
                Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight(),
                true);

        pixmap = new Pixmap(Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth(),
                Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight(),
                Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);

        BufferUtils.copy(pixels, 0, pixmap.getPixels(), pixels.length);
        PixmapIO.writePNG(Gdx.files.external("./screenshot_" + new Date().getTime() + ".png"), pixmap);

        pixmap.dispose();
        pixels = null;
    }
}
```

Calling `Screenshot().take()` will take the LibGDX render buffer and dump it in a PNG file. Exactly what I want.

My question is if there's a good way to 'capture' the print screen button. Is there a print screen keycode that I can use?

Comment: Use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) with this key code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10793610/300257

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thank you for your comment! Could you please advice me on how to do this correctly with a code example as an answer? If you could do that for me, I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that in LibGDX **you cannot**.

The way you are checking the keyboard input is

```
    Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(key)
```

where `key` is object of class [Keys](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.Keys.html) which **does not includes prtscr button**.

What's more - the *Keys* objects are integers so I tried to find out what button code of prtsrc is by checking:

```
    uiStage.addListener(new ClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(InputEvent event, int keycode)
        {
            System.out.println(keycode);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

and I got **0** on my computer. I have checked what **0** is in *Keys* class by printing

```
    System.out.println(Input.Keys.toString(42));
```

and the result was `Unknown`. I'm pretty surprised to be honest but it seems that LibGDX does not support PRINT_SCREEN button.

Probably there is a way to ommit LibGDX mechanism and use the platform specific function to check if prtsrc was clicked (internet says that it's ASCII code is **44**) but the answer for LibGDX itself seems to be - there is no way to do it.

Comment: That is absolutely unplanned for... I now want to know if the missing implementation has some sort of reason behind it... I wonder...

Comment: What comes to my mind is that maybe because prtscr button is not available on e.g. android virtual keyboard or it can be differ on different devices - maybe it worths to ask libgdx production team - I believe they will explain